# C++ demo function uses both a const argument that is a pointer why is this?

Tags: c++, function, functional-programming, c++17

In the `std::filesystem` c++17 library documentation there are multiple instances of an input to a function being a const and yet also using its reference.

```
void demo_exists(const fs::path& p, fs::file_status s = fs::file_status{});
```

Surely the `const` and the `&` contradict. My understanding is that `const` is used when you don't want the variable to be modified and an `&` when you want to mutate multiple arguments within the function without having to return them as an array after.

Surely using both `const` and `&` is oxymoronic and confusing or is there a reason why they are both used?

Thanks in advance

original example from the docs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists

Comment: No, they don't contradict each other. References can also make the code more performant because then the parameter doesn't necessarily have to be copied.

Comment: With `const fs::path& p` you declare that `p` is a reference to a constant `fs::path` object. The `const` means you can't modify `p`, and the reference means that you don't have to copy the whole object. Such references to constant object could also be used to bind to [rvalues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue), which means you can for example call this function with a *string* instead of an actual `path` object (i.e. `demo_exists("/some/path")` is valid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that const is used when you don't want the variable to be modified and an & when you want to mutate multiple arguments within the function without having to return them as an array after.

That is not quite correct. You pass by reference when you want to avoid a copy. Though since move-semantics have been introduced, many uses of passing by (`const`) reference are obsolote.

You declare the reference as `const` when the method does not modify the parameter and only non-const when it has to modify it.

Example:

```
void foo(const SomeLargeObject&); // pass by reference to avoid copy

void bar(int&);                   // pass non-const reference to modify the parameter
```

PS:

> C++ demo function uses both a const argument that is a **pointer** why is this?

There is not a single pointer here. What might be confusing is that the address-off operator and the symbol for reference types are the same: `&`. However, it has two very different meanings:

```
 int x = 0;
 int* pointer_to_x = &x;    // here it is address-of operator
 int& reference_to_x = x;   // here it declares reference_to_x as reference to int
```

PS2: For the sake of completeness I want to mention one more thing. The second unfortunate thingy in C++ here is that "references" usually refer to C++ references (see examples above). On the other hand the term "pass by reference" is used in a wider context and uses "reference" in the meaning of "some reference", ie it can be a reference or it can be a pointer. In the wider sense (*) those two are both pass-by-reference allowing the method to modify what is refered to:

```
void foo(int& x);   // A
void foo(int* x);   // B
```

In C++ references (A) should be prefered unless "no value" (ie a null-pointer) is a valid input.

(*) To be precise the pointer itself is actually passed by value.

Comment: I would argue that (B) is strictly pass-by-value (of the pointer).

Comment: Is it then best to always use void functions and always pass the values that would be returned?

Comment: @Tasty213 first of all, sorry but I am allergic to the term "void function" a function is more than its return type. Anyhow, no in general it is "better" to return the value when you want to return something. Consider `x = foo();` vs `foo(x);` ... on which function it is more obvious that `x` is the result of the function call?